# Resizing in Kivy makes blank space between widgets

Tags: python, kivy

I've created a basic GUI, to test scrollview and get a platform to build on further.
When resizing my window, there comes black space above my widgets, and there is also a lot of black space between them.

I've tried with "anchor" and "pos" but can't get the widgets to stay in the top of the window.

```
class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        sidepanel = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", size_hint=(None, 1), pos_hint={"x": 0.0, "y": 0.0})
        scroll = ScrollView(pos_hint={"x": 0.2, "y": 0.0})
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)

        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        for i in range(50):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=30)
            layout.add_widget(btn)


        sidepanel.add_widget(Button(text="Import Photos", size_hint=(1,0.2)))
        sidepanel.add_widget(Button(text="Create Report", size_hint=(1,0.2)))
        sidepanel.add_widget(Button(text="Save?", size_hint=(1,0.2)))
        sidepanel.add_widget(Button(text="Button 4", size_hint=(1,0.2)))


        scroll.add_widget(layout)


        root.add_widget(sidepanel)
        root.add_widget(scroll)

        return root
```

I would expect the sidepanel to stay the same size, and the scrollview containing "layout" to resize with the window. And all widgets should stay in the top.

Standard window

[image]

Resized window

[image]

Comment: I think your root widget size never changes, because you set it to Window.height at the moment the build method is run but then never update it.

Comment: Not sure how to update it, when it is running. I'll try to find out

Comment: Just don't give it a manual size, let it resize to fill the window as happens automatically by default.

Comment: Ok thanks - I'll try it out

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is stemming from your size specifications in your 'root' floatlayout. Try using:

`root = FloatLayout()`

where you don't specify any size instructions. It will know how to resize itself properly automatically with the window. Generally you want to avoid using both `size_hint` and `size` together on the same widget. Same goes for `pos_hint` and `pos`.

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: awesome! Have fun with kivy, it's a great tool :)